# Solution of a meme integral: $\int \frac{x \sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)^2}\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, polylogarithm

### Context

A few days ago I saw a meme published on a mathematics page in which they joked about the fact that $$\int\frac{x\sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)^2}\mathrm{d}x$$ was very long (and they put a screen shot of the result obtained using Wolfram)

(I avoid posting the whole screen because it is actually very very long, just open this [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate%20x%20sin%28x%29%2F%281%2Bcos%28x%29%5E2%29).)

### My work

However, out of curiosity I tried to do it and got the following result:

$${\color{blue}{\int_{0}^{x}\frac{t\sin(t)}{1+\cos(t)^2}\mathrm{d}t=-x\operatorname{tan^{-1}}(\cos(x))-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{(\sqrt{2}-1)^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)^2}\sin((2n-1)x)}}$$

> Which is ridiculously shorter than the whole result Wolfram gives haha

### Question

I would like to express the last series in terms of known functions, but I can't (I'm pretty sure it's the imaginary part of the dilogarithm, but I can't bring it back), could anyone help me?

I'll leave a [link for Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bnancfaubb?lang=it) if anyone wants to work on it.

Answer (score 13):

In the end I did it myself, it actually wasn't complicated, sorry.

$$-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{n}\frac{\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)^{2n-1}}{\left(2n-1\right)^{2}}\sin\left(\left(2n-1\right)x\right)-x\operatorname{tan^{-1}}\left(\cos\left(x\right)\right)$$
$$2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)^{2n-1}}{\left(2n-1\right)^{2}}\cos\left(\left(2n-1\right)\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)-x\operatorname{tan^{-1}}\left(\cos\left(x\right)\right)$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\left(-1\right)^{n}\right)\frac{\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)^{n}}{n^{2}}\cos\left(n\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)-x\operatorname{tan^{-1}}\left(\cos\left(x\right)\right)$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)^{n}}{n^{2}}\cos\left(n\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)^{n}}{n^{2}}\cos\left(n\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)-x\operatorname{tan^{-1}}\left(\cos\left(x\right)\right)$$
$$\Re\left[\text{Li}_{2}\left(\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)e^{i\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}\right)-\text{Li}_{2}\left(\left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)e^{i\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}\right)\right]-x\operatorname{tan^{-1}}\left(\cos\left(x\right)\right)$$

$$\Re\left[\text{Li}_{2}\left(i\left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)e^{ix}\right)-\text{Li}_{2}\left(i\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)e^{ix}\right)\right]-x\operatorname{tan^{-1}}\left(\cos\left(x\right)\right)$$

---

$$\color{blue}{\int_{0}^{x}\frac{t\sin\left(t\right)}{1+\cos\left(t\right)^{2}}\mathrm{d}t=2\Im\left[\text{Ti}_2((\sqrt{2}-1)e^{ix})\right]-x\cdot\operatorname{tan^{-1}}(\cos(x))}$$

Where:

- $\text{Li}_{\nu}(z)$ is the [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).
- $\text{Ti}_{\nu}(z):=\dfrac{\text{Li}_{\nu}(iz)-\text{Li}_{\nu}(-iz)}{2i}$ is the [inverse tangent integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_tangent_integral).

---

### Update: related additional formula

$$\color{blue}{\begin{align}\int\operatorname{tan^{-1}}(\cos(x))x^n\mathrm{d}x=&2n!\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(-1\right)^{\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor}\frac{x^{n-k}}{\left(n-k\right)!}\cdot\begin{cases}
\Re\left[\text{Ti}_{k+2}\left(\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)e^{ix}\right)\right]
&k\text{ is odd}\\
\Im\left[\text{Ti}_{k+2}\left(\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)e^{ix}\right)\right]&k\text{ is even}\end{cases}\\
=&2n!\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{x^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}\Im\left[i^k\cdot\text{Ti}_{k+2}\left(\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)e^{ix}\right)\right]\end{align}}$$

> It is related because:
> $$\int_{0}^{x}\frac{t^{n}\sin\left(t\right)}{1+\cos\left(t\right)^{2}}dt=-\operatorname{tan^{-1}}\left(\cos\left(x\right)\right)x^{n}+\int_{0}^{x}\operatorname{tan^{-1}}\left(\cos\left(t\right)\right)t^{n-1}dt$$

#### Generalization

Let:
$$\theta:=\frac{\sqrt{\alpha^2+1}-1}{\alpha}$$
Then:
$$\color{blue}{\begin{align}\int\operatorname{tan^{-1}}(\alpha\cdot\cos(x))x^n\mathrm{d}x=&2n!\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(-1\right)^{\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor}\frac{x^{n-k}}{\left(n-k\right)!}\cdot\begin{cases}
\Re\left[\text{Ti}_{k+2}\left(\theta e^{ix}\right)\right]
&k\text{ is odd}\\
\Im\left[\text{Ti}_{k+2}\left(\theta e^{ix}\right)\right]&k\text{ is even}\end{cases}\\
=&2n!\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{x^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}\Im\left[i^k\cdot\text{Ti}_{k+2}\left(\theta\cdot e^{ix}\right)\right]\end{align}}$$

The imaginary part can be computed with this serie:
$$\Im\left[i^{n}\cdot\text{Ti}_{n+2}\left(\theta  e^{ix}\right)\right]=-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{k}\frac{\theta^{2k-1}}{\left(2k-1\right)^{n+2}}\sin\left(\left(2k-1\right)x+\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)$$

I implemented it on [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/axkif9amjk?lang=it) if anyone wants to have fun with it.

---

### Update 2: related hyperbolic formula

Very small variation on the theme, just because maybe someone needs it and [Wolfram gives this very long result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate%20arctan%28cosh%28x%29%29dx)

$$\color{blue}{\begin{align}\int\operatorname{tan^{-1}}\left(\cosh(x)\right)\mathrm{d}x=&\frac{\pi}{2}x+\Im\left[\text{Li}_{2}\left(i\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)e^{x}\right)-\text{Li}_{2}\left(i\left(\sqrt{2}+1\right)e^{x}\right)\right]\\
=&\frac{\pi}{2}x+\text{Ti}_2\left(\left(\sqrt{2}+1\right)e^{-x}\right)-\text{Ti}_2\left(\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)e^{-x}\right)\end{align}}$$

#### Generalization of hypergeometric formula

Let: $$\alpha>0\text{ and }\theta^{\pm}=\frac{\sqrt{\alpha^2+1}\pm1}{\alpha}$$

Then:

$$\color{blue}{\begin{matrix}\displaystyle\int\operatorname{tan^{-1}}\left(\alpha\cdot\cosh\left(x\right)\right)x^{n}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+n!\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{x^{n-k}}{\left(n-k\right)!}\left(\text{Ti}_{k+2}\left(\theta^{+}e^{-x}\right)-\text{Ti}_{k+2}\left(\theta^{-}e^{-x}\right)\right)\end{matrix}}$$

I implemented also it on [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ilspszctbl?lang=it) if anyone wants to have fun with it.

Comment: An interesting addition is that the non-elementary part is equivelent to $ -\frac{\pi}{2}x + \frac{1}{4} \sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{1}{2n-1} \beta (sin^{2}(x); 1/2, n)$ where $\beta (x; a, b)$ is the incomplete beta function. This also means that when $x= \pi n + \frac{\pi}{2}$ that the sum part of this is equal to catalans constant.

Comment: What are $\mathrm{Li}_2$ and $\mathrm{Ti}_2$?

Comment: @tparker $\text{Li}_{\nu}(z)$ is the polylogarithm and $\text{Ti}_{\nu}(z)$ is the inverse tangent integral (I added it to the answer now)